# Are strings given a memory address if they're declared but not initialized? I need help understanding some strange in a data recovery excercise

Tags: c, arrays, string, cs50

So I'm in the middle of recover.c pset for CS50, and I set up my code to just print what the file name will be whenever it sees a jpeg header (eg, "000.jpg\n001.jpg").

The following code gave weird results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void writeJPG(char *file_name, int file_num);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //check for valid inputs
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("file could not be opened\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int file_num = 0;
    char file_name[7];

    typedef uint8_t BYTE; //define BYTE type

    BYTE test[512];
    BYTE *test_p = test;

    int a = fread(test_p, 512, 1, file);
    do
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 512; k++)
        {
            a = fread(test_p+k, 1, 1, file);
        }

        if (test[0] == 0xff && test[1] == 0xd8 && test[2] == 0xff)
        {
            if (test[3] >= 0xe0 && test[3] <= 0xef)
            {
                writeJPG(file_name, file_num);
                printf("%s\n", file_name);
                file_num++;
            }
        }

        /*for(int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
        {
            //if (*(test_p + i) != 0)
            //{
                printf("%i ", *(test_p + i));
            //}
        }
        //printf("%i\n", *test_p);
        printf("\n\n");*/
        //a = fread(test, 1, 1, file);

    }
    while (a == 1);
}

void writeJPG(char * file_name, int file_num)
{
    //char file_name[7];
    //file_name[0] = '\0';
    if (file_num < 10)
    {
        sprintf(file_name, "00%i.jpg", file_num);
    }
    else if (file_num < 100)
    {
        sprintf(file_name, "0%i.jpg", file_num);
    }
    else if (file_num < 1000)
    {
        sprintf(file_name, "%i.jpg", file_num);
    }
    //return file_name;
}
```

output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRAol.png

working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void writeJPG(char *file_name, int file_num);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //check for valid inputs
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("file could not be opened\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int file_num = 0;
    char file_name[] = "000.jpg";

    typedef uint8_t BYTE; //define BYTE type

    BYTE test[512];
    BYTE *test_p = test;

    int a = fread(test_p, 512, 1, file);
    do
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 512; k++)
        {
            a = fread(test_p+k, 1, 1, file);
        }

        if (test[0] == 0xff && test[1] == 0xd8 && test[2] == 0xff)
        {
            if (test[3] >= 0xe0 && test[3] <= 0xef)
            {
                writeJPG(file_name, file_num);
                printf("%s\n", file_name);
                file_num++;
            }
        }

        /*for(int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
        {
            //if (*(test_p + i) != 0)
            //{
                printf("%i ", *(test_p + i));
            //}
        }
        //printf("%i\n", *test_p);
        printf("\n\n");*/
        //a = fread(test, 1, 1, file);

    }
    while (a == 1);
}

void writeJPG(char * file_name, int file_num)
{
    //char file_name[7];
    //file_name[0] = '\0';
    if (file_num < 10)
    {
        sprintf(file_name, "00%i.jpg", file_num);
    }
    else if (file_num < 100)
    {
        sprintf(file_name, "0%i.jpg", file_num);
    }
    else if (file_num < 1000)
    {
        sprintf(file_name, "%i.jpg", file_num);
    }
    //return file_name;
}
```

output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dlkc.png

The only thing different in the working code is that the string file_name is initialized to "000.jpg". I need help understanding why this one works, and why the original bad code still incremented once, then stopped.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post text as pictures. Simply copy&paste text into your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

`char file_name[];` is not a proper definition. Because this declaration violates a rule in C 2018 6.7 7 (”If an identifier for an object is declared with no linkage, the type for the object shall be complete by the end of its declarator,…”), the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Oddly, this rule does not appear in a constraint and does not appear to require a diagnostic message according to the rules of the C standard. However, any decent C compiler will give you an error message for it. Ensure warning and error messages for your compiler are turned on and pay attention to them.

You can reserve space for `file_name` by specifying a size for the array, such as `char file_name[1000];`. It looks like your program will only require a certain amount of space for the file name. You should calculate this maximum space, including the terminating null character, and reserve that much space or more.

Comment: my bad, it was originally defined char file_name[7];

Comment: @MichaelWeiser: Seven characters is not enough to hold a file name of three digits, a period, the three characters in “jpg”, and a terminating null character.

Comment: so how come it compiled and ran? i thought for strings you dont have to account for the null terminator

Comment: @MichaelWeiser: It compiled and ran because the compiler did not detect the error. The compiler is not required to trace your use of objects all throughout the program, and this is sometimes effectively impossible. Every *string* must have a null terminator. You can have arrays of `char` without nulls, but then you are responsible for knowing what data is in them, including the length of the useful data if that varies. But when you use arrays of `char` with C standard library functions that expect to read or write strings, such as `sprintf`, then you must have space for the null terminator.

Comment: ok that makes sense. Do you have an idea why it did increment once?